# react native expo fast image is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I saw this article:

```
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/react-native-fast-image
```

I install expo react native fast image. So I want to use it but I get this err message:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "FastImageView" was not found in the UIManager.
```

Code:

```
...
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
...
      { /* Modal Shipping */ }
      <Modal 
        isVisible={modalView}
        swipeDirection="down"
        swipeThreshold={20}
        propagateSwipe={true}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
      >
          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', padding: 12, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 12, padding: 12, borderWidth: 4, borderColor: '#ac67f9'}}>
            <FastImage source={{uri: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/QSIAAOSw3gNggE1r/s-l225.webp'}} resizeMode="contain" />
          </View>
      </Modal>
```

Comment: can you try add style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} and change resizemode like this resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}

Comment: Run pod install and rebuilding the app

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I use expo

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to install react-native-fast-image to my expo project. Here is what I've done:

- Make sure you run the `eas build -p all --profile development` Ensure
  [`eas-cli`](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/getting-started/#install-the-latest-eas-cli) is installed prior to run this script.
- After running it, you will have an `eas.json` file in the root dir of
  the project.
- The next step is to run `expo run:ios` or `expo run:android`, then
  you will notice the generated native folders (android, ios) in the
  root dir again...

All should work just fine after these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any new option for this? In expo project, `"FastImageView was not found in the UIManager."`  still occurs.

Answer (score -2):

Use this package it is super fast

[expo fast image](https://github.com/muhammadwafa/expo-fast-image)

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Comment: Doesn't work with my expo 47